# Swift Modifying Tableviews with arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

Hi I'm nearly done with my personal project but came up stuck when I was trying modify my table view with my array. 
Here's my function that I'm using; it takes the data I have and puts it respectively into the annotation name, coordinates of the annotation and then goes into the table view, which is all contained within a custom map callout.

The way I set it up is that using the i value it counts off and matches the name and coordinates perfectly, and if I put i into "index" for the item list it does exactly that by counting them off.

My issue is that I want to be able to display multiple lines of information within the tableview, which is the use of the "for _ in 0...1". However, when I do this in conjunction with the index=i I get this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni7KM.png).

Would anyone know how I would go about getting 2 lines of info into each pool's tableview? The end result would have the correct pool name and location(which is already done) and then the correct corresponding address and indoor/outdoor description.

My code is below, any help would be greatly appreciated I've searched everywhere but can't find anything useful that wouldn't require me to redo everything.

```
func populatePoolsList() {
    let names = ["BSC Waltham", "Weston Golf Club", "BSC Wellesley", "Life Time Natick"]

    let coordinates = [
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.400366, longitude: -71.279059),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.361025, longitude: -71.287842),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.348945, longitude: -71.228759),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.312967, longitude: -71.394940),
        ]
    let wishlist = ["444 Winter St, Indoor Pool", "275 Meadowbrook Rd", "Outdoor Pool", "Someplace in Wellesley", "Both Infoor and Outdoor Pools", "a place in Natick", "Either pools"]
     let items = ["444 Winter St, Indoor Pool", "275 Meadowbrook Rd", "Outdoor Pool", "Someplace in Wellesley", "Both Infoor and Outdoor Pools", "a place in Natick", "Either pools"]

    pools = []
    for i in 0..<kPoolsWishListManagerNumberOfPools {
        let name = names[i]
        let avatar = UIImage(named: "outdoorpool 2")!
        var wishlist = [String]()
        for _ in 0...1 {
            let index = i
            wishlist.append(items[index])
        }

        let pool = Pool(name: name, avatar: avatar)
        pool.wishList = wishlist
        pool.location = coordinates[i]
        pools.append(pool)
    }
}
```

Comment: In the table view, are you trying to present the address on the first line and the location type on the second line? @Jackson.R

Comment: Yes that's what I was going for, but honestly I'll take just having the two bits of information in any order in the tableview as long as they're in the right pool's annotation haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is confusing because you have a constant `wishlist` and later a local variable `wishlist` which are different objects.

You are appending the same item twice because you are not using the current loop index but the outmost index `i`

Maybe you mean in the first iteration items 0 and 1 are used, in the second items 2 and 3 and so on.

```
let index = i * 2
wishlist = [items[index], items[index+1]]
```

which requires that the constant `wishlist` contains at least `kPoolsWishListManagerNumberOfPools * 2` items otherwise you get an out-of-range crash.

---

Basically if the data is static anyway I recommend to extend the pool initializer

```
init(name: String, avatar: UIImage, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, wishlist : [String])
```

and populate the array this more efficient way

```
func populatePoolsList() {
   pools = [Pool(name: "BSC Waltham", avatar: UIImage(named: "outdoorpool 2")!, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.400366, longitude: -71.279059), wishlist : "444 Winter St, Indoor Pool", "275 Meadowbrook Rd")
            Pool(name: "Weston Golf Club", avatar: UIImage(named: "outdoorpool 3")!, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.361025, longitude: -71.287842), wishlist : "275 Meadowbrook Rd", "Outdoor Pool",
            ... ]
```

or save the data in a JSON file on disk and decode the JSON into the `Pool` instances.

Comment: The function you put up works for the first annotation (BSC Waltham) but my primary issue is getting consequent annotations (such as BSC Wellesley) to be filled with correct information. I'm pretty new to coding and loops/indexes in general which is why my loops are messy; initially I thought I would have to use "i" to act as a counter for every two strings in the array but now I'm not sure if thats possible

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up going with the first suggestion you put in since in my opinion I personally prefer operating with integers and it was more of a quick fix that I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Your wishlist values are not grouped consistently. Try changing wishlist to this:

```
let wishlist = ["444 Winter St, Indoor Pool",
                "275 Meadowbrook Rd, Outdoor Pool",
                "Someplace in Wellesley, Both Infoor and Outdoor Pools",
                "a place in Natick, Either pools"]
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried, but it just ends up putting both the address and description in the same line and the next pools info in the second line.